# C++ 11 :How to prevent from vector loop to updated while iterating without locks

Tags: c++11, timer

i have timer in my app while callback its function each 100mms
using :

```
timer_ptr new_timer = lib::make_shared<lib::asio::steady_timer>
```

now in side this loop i have loop which iterate vector and do updates to its members .

```
//copy the members which are relevant in this point in time
        con_list m_connectionsLocalTmp = m_global_connections;
        for (const auto it : m_connectionsLocalTmp )
        {
           ...
           ...
        }
```

The m_global_connections vector get filled in the application none stop
so each timer callback i copy the elements that are relevant to this point in   time , i know its not efficient but i didn't find any better way,
the problem is 
what happens when the timer called again and the loop is not finished but it get updated from

```
con_list m_connectionsLocalTmp = m_global_connections;
```

and now it looping new set of elements .
how can i order this logic in the callback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to lock, either using a mutex or a spinlock based on at atomic variable. 
A better technique would be to have two vectors and swap them accordingly.
In this case I jsut use a mutex for simplicity.

```
    con_list m_connectionsLocalTmp;
    //copy the members which are relevant in this point in time
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_i_mutex);
      while(!connectionsLocalTmp.empty()){ }
      std::swap(connectionsLocalTmp, m_global_connections);
    }
    for (const auto it : m_connectionsLocalTmp )
    {
       ...
       ...
    }
```

Comment: why the swap is better then just copy vector to vector ?

Comment: also i need to keep the m_global_connections as is , as it the connection repository of the app

Comment: The `swap` is better as it exchanges two pointers. The documentation states: "Does not invoke any move, copy, or swap operations on individual elements."

Answer (score 1):

As @dau_sama states you need a lock from a `mutex`. However I would use the built-in specialisation of [`swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap).

Hacking @dau_sama example:

```
con_list m_connectionsLocalTmp;
//copy the members which are relevant in this point in time
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_i_mutex);
  while(!connectionsLocalTmp.empty()){ }
  m_global_connections.swap(connectionsLocalTmp);
}
for (const auto it : m_connectionsLocalTmp )
{
   // ...
}
```

However, I would not use a native vector for this but a `queue` container adapter, and [`condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) to wait on data. This gets rid of the swap, the polling loop and processes the data as it appears.

Comment: why would you use queue and not vector ? and why condition_variable ?

Comment: also i need to keep the m_global_connections as is , as it the connection repository of the app

Comment: It is more a question of semantics. I view incoming data as a stream and a  more natural way to view that is a queue. While polling every 100ms and processing everything that has turned up in the last tenth of a second works, I feel that processing data as it arrives is more elegant. I also work in an environment where 100ms is a looong time!

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe @dau_sama and I have misunderstood your issue.  We both thought you were processing data, not updating it.